# Debuging with IIS in Angular 5 SPA Template

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, templates, single-page-application

I have created a new Angular5 \ Dotnet core 2.0 Project with the latest version of the Angular spa template =>

`dotnet new --install Microsoft.DotNet.Web.Spa.ProjectTemplates::2.0.0`

But when I create a Project with =>

`dotnet new angular -o`

IISTest and switch the debug settings to the following =>

[image: debug config]

I always get the following error =>

[image: Error with IIS]

In IIS I created a new website on port 333 and a No Managed Code Pool.

I did the same with the Angular 4 Template and there it works all fine!

Does anyone have an idea what this problem is?

p.s. when I run this Project IIS Express it works

Comment: I am working on exactly the same issue here. I can't  see your images (behind a firewall at work) but I assume the error says something about `angular cli` not listening or the `502.5 error` page is up. If you can, can you post the version of the `OS` and the `cli` tools version as well,also the `dotnet` version please. Also do you have IntelliSense for css classes when you code the views?

Comment: @michael any luck getting this working?